# load test of secured web-service

Tags: web-services, testing, security, load-testing, ws-security

For an application I need to do a load test for a webservice which is secured with WS Security Username/Password.
My Primary goal would be to conclude whether its possible or not and if yes which tool/approach is best.

Answer (score 1):

The first and primitive idea is to write own realization of protocol and than implement into jmeter.

Comment: hi Zemike, can u give more description about write realization of protocol or any good tutorial for it

Comment: I don't remember tutorial about it. If shortly, you must write class that implement "JavaSamplerClient" interface of JMeter, compile your project and put in jmeter/lib/ext. Then in JMeter you must select sampler "JavaRequest". It has dropdown list where you can choose your class. Interface has four methods: 1) describe sampler arguments 2) runTest is method going through cycles 3) setup is executed before runTest 4) tearDown after runtest

Answer (score 1):

Is the service using message signatures (section 8 of the WS-Security spec) or encryption (section 9)?

If not, then many load-testing tools, such as our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) product, can test services using WS-Security.  If signatures and/or encryption are in use, then your choices will be limited to those tools that have implemented support for those parts of the specification.